# How to keep the timestamp unchanged while coverting xlsx to csv using R?

Tags: r

My data looks like this for a column which contains both character and date rows:

```
     "COLUMNXYZ"
```

row#1   All is well

row#2   Yes you are right

row#3   1/5/2015 0:00

row#4   1/5/2015 0:15

While reading the data csv the time stamp is read as:

42009

42009.01042 and so on.

I assume that the problem is because of the column contains both character and date rows it is causing a problem. Also I saw and earlier solution on SO for a similar problem, but the rows only contained date in those examples, and the problem was resolved by applying the following code but it does not work in my case.

Steps tried:
XLSX CSV convert:

```
# Create a vector of Excel files to read
files.to.read = list.files(pattern="xlsx")

# Read each file and write it to csv
lapply(files.to.read, function(f) {

  df = read.xlsx(f, sheet=1)

  write.csv(df, gsub("xlsx", "csv", f), row.names=FALSE)
})

#Restoring the date format
DateandTime <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(dataset$ColumnXYZ,"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M",tz="")) ,format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")

#Add time stamp in a seperate column to the original dataset
dataset$Period <- DateandTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me and your example file:

Step 1: Create a second column in Excel from your only example column with the following function: `=TEXT(A2,"DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss")`. Somehow this did not affect the strings, but converted datetimes into strings, which is what I was after.

Step 2: Run the following command in R (change the path to `.xlsx` file, obviously):

```
d = readxl::read_excel("~/SO_Examples/temp1.xlsx", 
                       col_types = 'text')
d
# A tibble: 4 × 2
            col1                col2
               <chr>               <chr>
1        All is well         All is well
2  Yes you are right   Yes you are right
3              42009 05/01/2015 00:00:00
4 42009.010416666664 05/01/2015 00:15:00
```

As you can see, the first, original column, is indeed no good. But the second, which I created in Step 1, seems to be ok. From here you could parse dates as you see fit.

Hope this helps. If you have many excel files, this likely won't scale well, unfortunately.

**Addition**

For a different solution, which is also not great but does capture dates, try this:

```
d = readxl::read_excel("~/SO_Examples/temp1.xlsx", 
                       col_types = 'date')
d
# A tibble: 4 × 1
                 col1 
               <dttm>
1                <NA>
2                <NA>
3 2015-01-05 00:00:00
4 2015-01-05 00:15:00
```

This will generate tons of warnings, but handle datetimes correctly. Perhaps you could then run the same code again, this time loading data as text, and combine the two datasets by keeping the relevant parts from each load attempt?

Comment: actually i have 60+ excel files and i don't want to have manual intervention before reading the files.I am looking for a solution which solves the problem after reading it or some automated way which can ensure that timestamp remains intact may be before reading as well. Anyways thanks.

Comment: Good point. I added another option, which may be more helpful, but is perhaps not ideal as well. The real issue here is with Excel, not R, so correct solution would be to fix the contents of Excel sheets, but that can be tricky to do programmatically.

Comment: This solution partially helps me. I am still figuring out the way to completely automate the process.Thanks anyways appreciate it.